# Do drivers gain experience if they faint in battle?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

If a driver faints during a battle and I defeat an enemy without reviving them, does the unconscious driver still get experience points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, fainted drivers still gain experience while unconscious. You can see the EXP earned on top of the driver's body.

[image: Nia gaining experience while unconscious]

Comment: Does this revive them if they level up (which is normally an instant full heal)?

Comment: @Toomai I had a level up once, but it was at the end of a battle. I think they weren't healed to full immediately, but I don't remember for sure.